# Context.Connection.ClientCertificate is sometimes null

Tags: .net-core, openssl, client-certificates, c#-11.0

- DotNet7
- openssl generated certificate pem and key pem
- self signed certificate generated with https://certificatetools.com/

I have 2 certificates, one self signed as a negative test in pfx format and another generated on linux with openssl.

I have tested the validation of the custom ca chain with the self signed pfx and the client certificate pem, and all is fine (rejects the former, validates the latter).  My issue is getting the certificate sent to the server to be validated.

Here is how I am sending the certificates:

```
async Task PerformGet(X509Certificate2 certificate2) {

  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
  handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
  handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate2);

  var ssClient = new HttpClient(handler);
  ssClient.BaseAddress = baseUri;

  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "Action/Certificate");

  var response = await ssClient.SendAsync(request);

  return response;
}
```

I read the Self Signed cert from a pfx file:

```
var ssPfx = File.ReadAllBytes("not.a.thing.pfx");
var ssCert = new X509Certificate2(ssPfx);
```

I read the client cert from its pem

```
var certPem = File.ReadAllText("my.cert.pem");
var certKeyPem = File.ReadAllText("my.key.pem");
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromEncryptedPem(certPem, certKeyPem, "my");
cert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
```

The first certificate gets through fine, so you can be sure that I've set up kestral to allow certificates.

The problem is that the client cert does not get through.  Context.Connection.ClientCertificate is null.

I've tried loading the client certificate from

- just the cert.pem text
- both cert.pem and key.pem
- both cert.pem and key.pem converting to pfx (as above using cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12) and cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx))
- exporting the certificate as pfx and reimporting in.  I also checked that I could install the pfx and it seems perfectly valid.

I don't get any errors or any indication of what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks ^_^

PS: I noticed that loading the self signed cert from it's own pem files (all combos) didn't work either so maybe I'm exporting the pfx incorrectly?

**UPDATE**

I have narrowed down the issue to the client certificate not being verified.  I have added the root ca cert and intemediate to the device certificates, but still no luck.  That one really confused me!

Is it possible to set up a custom trust store when calling either `X509Certificate2.Verify()` or `HttpClient.SendAsync(request)`